# jQuery could not set html to div in hide and show

Tags: jquery

in first of rendering page i can use `.html()` to setting any string on div, after hide that and show again jquery could not set string.

**my problem is set html after hide and show again element.**

jQuery:

```
$('#view_topic').click(function(){
    $('#view_port').show();
    $('#view_port').html('HELLO');
})

$('[id^="close_"]').click(function(){
    $('#view_port').hide('fast');    
});
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<li id='view_topic' ><a href="javascript:void(0);">VIEW</a></li>
<div id='view_port' class='jqcontextmenu both view_port' >
    <div style='position: absolute;top:0px;left: 4px;'><a href='javascript:void(0);'><img src='../UI/images/close.png' id='close_dialogs'/></a></div>
        <div id='view_port_table'>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: There's no #view_topic element in your html.

Comment: where is the #view_topic element?

Comment: i have this element and i can show and hide that. this is simple of my code ok?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You wanted to set a string on `div` using `.html()` after hiding and showing it again?

Comment: @vher2, yes my problem is that. can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div id='view_topic'>
    <a href="#">VIEW</a>
</div>

<div id='view_port'>
    <div id='close_dialogs'>
        <a href='#'><img src='http://placehold.it/200x200'/></a>
    </div>
    <div id='view_port_table'>

    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#view_topic a').click(function(){
    $('#view_port').show();
    $('#view_port_table').html('HELLO');
    return false;
})

$('[id^="close_"] a').click(function(){
    $('#view_port').hide('fast');
    return false;
});
```

**CSS**

```
#view_port{
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/gaAMR/1/

Answer (score 1):

There is no element  `view_topic`  use  `view_port`

```
$('#view_topic').click(function(){      
    $('#view_port').show();
      $('#view_port').html('HELLO');

})

$('[id^="close_"]').click(function(){
    $('#view_port').hide('fast');    
});


 <a href='javascript:void(0);' id="view_topic">view topic</a>
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar, i dont have any problem to show and hide. my problem is set html after hide and show again element.

Comment: I get that, but his code, previously was trying to attach a click handler to show that element (that means it is hidden) on the same element. So, the user would have no access on it.

Answer (score 0):

Add an element in your HTML like

```
     <a href='javascript:void(0);' id="view_topic">view topic</a>
```

$('#view_topic').click() only trigger click of an element with id="view_topic"